# how to differentiate between NSString object converted into NSData and UIImage object converted into NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am developing an application in which i will be sending a string to peer(after converting it into NSData object) and also an UIImage again by converting into NSData object.

Now at receiving end i have a receive method

```
- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data
            fromPeer:(NSString *)peer
           inSession:(GKSession *)session
             context:(void *)context
```

My problem is that,same receive method is called every time i send any data,and i have to use image and text data differently.

So how can i know,whether i data that i have received is a NSString object converted into NSData or it's UIImage data converted into NSData.

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's `GKRocket` sample code, specifically the implementation of `sendData:ofType` and `receiveData:fromPeer:inSession:context:` in [SessionManager.m](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GKRocket/Listings/Classes_SessionManager_m.html). You will need to define a set of "types" specific to your application and send them as a header in the `NSData` payload, and then read the header on the receiving end to determine how to handle the payload appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to define another parameter (ofType) in recieveData that distinguishes what type of data is being sent:

```
(void) receiveData:(NSData *)data ofType: (bool type) fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context
```

Comment: i could not get you.I am sending an NSData object in both cases.What you mean by dataofType?Can you please elaborate.because in any case i will receive same type of object.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The `context` parameter is supposed to be arbitrary data sent to provide a context or meaning for the sent data. It can be anything converted to data, even complex objects.</strike>

In this case a simple bool value would do.

*The above is incorrect. The context is set by the receiver to distinguish between multiple sessions or peers.* -- TechZen

Comment: NSError *er=[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"anurag" code:123 userInfo:nil];
  
  
  
[mSession sendDataToAllPeers:myData withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:&er];

Comment: this is what i am using while sending the data.How can i use context in it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the `context` is set on by the receiver to be passed to its own delegate. It's apparently intended to distinguish between multiple sessions.